# Django logout() returns none

Tags: python, django, logout

Morning everyone

Im using django logout() to end my sessions just like django docs says :

**views.py**

```
class Logout(View):
    def logout_view(request):
        logout(request) 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```

and im calling it from this url :

urls.py

```
url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout.as_view(), name = "logout"),
```

Buttttttt it's not working, when i do a trace i find that the function :

```
 def logout_view(request):
```

it's returning "none" and it's nos entering to execute the code inside...

Please help me !

Comment: Which "django docs"? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout says something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a built in [`logout`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout) view. I would use that rather than writing your own.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

url(r'^logout/$', 
    auth_views.logout, 
    {'next_page': reverse_lazy('cost_control_app:login')},
    name='logout',
)
```

If you want to write your own `logout` view, then I would stick with a function based view. There's no need to use a class based view here. The docs on [logging a user out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) have an example.

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Then change the url pattern to

```
url(r'^logout/$', logout_view, name="logout"),
```

If you really want to write a class based view, then you need to fix your `Logout` view. See Joey's answer for more info about this.

Comment: Exactly, just found out that trying, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious, why do you have the method named `logout_view()`? By default, nothing is going to call that method. You need to change the name to match the HTTP verb which will be used to call the page. For instance, if it's going to be a `GET` request, you would change it to:

```
def get(self, request):
```

If you want it to be a POST request, you would change it to:

```
def post(self, request):
```

This is the standard way that class-based views work in Django. Also, you may want to look at the [documentation for class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/), as this may give you a better idea of their workings and what they can provide to you. (Hint: There is a built-in [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview))

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, i just removed the class logout(View) and call the def from the url without the "as_view" and it works. Thanks to all !